# Error: Type of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed

Tags: perl

I am getting the error

> Type of  of argument to keys on reference must be unblessed hasref or arrayref at xxxx.pl line 6518

Part of the script is

```
    ndr_log("Processing file: $file [$filesize bytes] Portion: $portion; Billing Date/MDate: $portion_date/$filemtime; Reading Proc: [$entries/$entries_reading/$entries_n15]: $reading_proc", 'Info');

    if (!defined $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{mtime}
            or $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{mtime} < $filemtime) {

        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{mtime}    = $filemtime;
        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{entries}  = $entries;
        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{readings} = $entries_reading;
        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{n15}      = $entries_n15;
        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{proc}     = $reading_proc;
        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{ok}       = $meter_ok;
        $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{nok}      = $meter_nok;
    }
    else {
        DbgPlain("Ignoring file: $file; this is older result; never version exists: $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{mtime}");
    }

} # for files

# Create Report
#
my @REPORT;

for (sort keys $BILL) {  ### Line 6518

    my $portion = $_;

    for ( sort keys $BILL->{$portion} ) {

        my $portion_date = $_;

        #ndr_log("Portion: $portion on $portion_date")

        my $entries         = $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{entries};
        my $entries_reading = $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{readings};
        my $entries_n15     = $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{n15};
        my $reading_proc    = $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{proc};
        my $meter_ok        = $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{ok};
        my $meter_nok       = $BILL->{$portion}->{$portion_date}->{nok};
```

Is there anyway to solve it?

I have in my new server ActivePerl 5.16.3 build 1604 and in the one that works Build 1603. Is it a version issue?

Comment: Please don't rewrite error messages. Copy and paste them. You will introduce typos that could hide valuable information.

Comment: Is $BILL an object? If it is, you shouldn't dereference it at all, not even to peek into its internal data (as in `$BILL->{$portion}`), you should call its methods instead. To iterate over the keys, there should be a method providing the list.

Comment: Perl 5.14 introduced [auto dereferencing](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Array-and-hash-container-functions-accept-references) as an experimental feature, but it was removed again in 5.24. But not on objects.

Comment: The difference in behaviour isn't due to AP 1603 vs AP 1604.

Answer (score 2):

If `$BILL` is a blessed object, getting its [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys) makes no sense. It might have a method to provide a list of the "keys" that you can then use as method names or parameters to a universal getter - but we don't know, as you haven't shown how $BILL is populated and what class it's been blessed to.

There were some changes in the behaviour of [keys](http://p3rl.org/keys) and references. To stay on the safe side, don't use it at all, dereference the reference:

```
keys %$BILL
```

But that applies to plain non-blessed hash references only. Applying dereference on an object breaks encapsulation (and note that `$BILL->{$portion}` dereferences the object, too).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> **Line 1618:**  for (sort keys $BILL) {
> ```

`$BILL` is a scalar value (starts with `$`), specifically a reference to a hash as can be seen how it was used earlier. You need to call `keys` on the hash itself and not on the reference to it. To do this you need to dereference it to get to the hash and call `keys` on it, i.e. use `keys %$BILL` not `keys $BILL`.

Comment: While you should use `keys %$ref` instead `keys $ref` (because the latter was an experimental feature that was abandoned), that's not the problem the OP is having. Switching to `keys %$ref` may or may not help. (I didn't downvote.)